# Android NDK linking

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am trying to build an android application that calls into a C++ backend.  This backend uses ZeroMQ for messaging.  Per the [android build page](http://www.zeromq.org/build%3aandroid) on the ZeroMQ guide, I have built a native toolchain of ndk version 6 and used that to (successfully) build ZeroMQ.

However, when I build my own .so with the JNI implementations, I can't seem to make everything load properly.  Specifically, if I call *System.LoadLibrary("zmq")*, this completes successfully, but if I then call *System.LoadLibrary("my_lib")* I always get an UnsatisfiedLinkError complaining that:

```
Cannot load library reloc_library[1244]:   29 cannot locate zmq_msg_init'...
```

The libmy_lib.so has been generated several different ways, each with no success.  After generating it, I always copies libmy_lib.so (as well as libzmq.so) to my android project's folder: libs/armeabi/.

```
# Compile all object files - this part was done for all options
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -fpic -c Client_Events.cpp \
Client Wrapper.cpp jni.cpp -I /opt/android-root/include/ -I /my/project/specific/stuff

# Option 1 - Don't link the lib in at all
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -shared  \
-Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so -o libmy_lib.so jni.o Client_Events.o Client_Wrapper.o 

# Option 2 - Link ZeroMQ in statically
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -shared  \
-Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so -o libmy_lib.so jni.o Client_Events.o Client_Wrapper.o \
libzmq.a libstdc++.a -Wl,--whole-archive    

# Option 3 - Explicitly link ZeroMQ in dynamically
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -shared  \
-Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so -o libmy_lib.so jni.o Client_Events.o Client_Wrapper.o \
-L /opt/android-root/lib/ -lzmq
```

With each of these options I tried both explicitly calling *System.LoadLibrary("zmq")* before loading my own library and not.  Nothing varied the results.  Using nm confirms that, at least in the case of option #2, the missing symbol *zmq_msg_init* is indeed present in libmy_lib.so.

Any ideas as to why it cannot find the ZeroMQ symbols that are linked in?

Comment: Check that your library is actually in the apk by opening it as a zip file, and check that it's actually getting extracted when installed on the device (probably easiest on an emulator).  Also considering running a test where you have a native lib with no dependencies - ie, grab the one out of the hello-jni ndk sample.

Comment: I was able to fix this by linking zeroMQ statically, but the c++ stl support dynamically.

Answer (score 14):

I just learnt how to compile a 2nd library and link it to my main library in android ndk. Let me see if I am of any use to you.

The following is how I create my 2nd library (In my case, I build bullet physics library and the irrlicht rendering engine as 2 separate libraries for my game).

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := HEADER FILES 
LOCAL_MODULE := bullet
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SRC FILES

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:%=-I%) -O3 -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then copy your libxxxx.so (In my case, libbullet.so and libirrlicht.so) to your jni folder. And in your main library .mk file add the following.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := (includes for bullet)
LOCAL_MODULE := bullet
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libbullet.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := (includes for irrlicht)
LOCAL_MODULE := irrlicht
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libirrlicht.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := (includes for bullet + includes for irrlicht + includes for main code)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main code src files

LOCAL_MODULE := gamescript

LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:%=-I%) -O3 -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lOpenSLES -landroid -ldl -llog

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bullet irrlicht

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And now, add all the libraries to your java code in right order.

```
System.loadLibrary("bullet");
System.loadLibrary("irrlicht");
System.loadLibrary("gamescript");
```

Comment: This has worked better.  However, it still refuses to load, this time because it is looking for libzmq.so.1, rather than libzmq.so, even if libzmq.so.1 is also copied into the directory (and appears in the apk).

Comment: If your library (libgamescript.so) or your sub library (libbullet.so) is using a 3rd party library (like in my case, libstlport.so) the your need to load stlport from java before you load your other libs. (first do system.loadLibrary("stlport");)

Comment: For me, that is libgnustl_shared.so and I do successfully load System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared") first.  However, it still claims an inability to find libraries I have previously successfully loadLibrary'ed.

Comment: The answer does work in all cases for me. I doubt you are following the same order. Also one more doubt, are you building it for many architectures?

Comment: Just a note: the Android NDK included document `${NDK}/doc/PREBUILTS.html` describes the details.