# Crash when launching project with two .so files

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, apk

I try to build my project, that have two .so files:
libTheGame.so
liblua.so
Both is in the apk, but project crash when I launch it with:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native
>   library: /data/data/com.piotrekb.theGame/lib/libTheGame.so

I can build and lunch project with both so, but without lua library added to TheGame :/
But when I add

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := lua
```

crash happen :/

This is my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
LOCAL_MODULE    := lua
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/llex.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lapi.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/loadlib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lvm.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lundump.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lauxlib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lparser.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lgc.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lobject.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lstrlib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lbaselib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ldebug.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lmem.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ltable.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/loslib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ldo.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ltablib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/liolib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ldump.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ldblib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lstate.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lctype.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lcode.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lcorolib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lzio.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lmathlib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lbitlib.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/ltm.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lstring.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lopcodes.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/linit.c \
./Libs/lua-5.2.0/src/lfunc.c  
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/Libs/cml-1_0_2 -I$(STLPORT_BASE)/stlport
LOCAL_MODULE    := TheGame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ./UISystem/UISystem.cpp ./ScriptSystem/ScriptSystem.cpp ./World3D/World3D.cpp ./ResourceSystem/ResourceSystem.cpp ./Renderer/Image.cpp \
 ./Renderer/Model3D.cpp ./LevelSystem/LevelSystem.cpp ./Renderer/ShaderProgram.cpp ./Common/Common.cpp ./Common/Engine.cpp ./Common/InDataBunch.cpp \
 ./Common/OutDataBunch.cpp ./Input/Input.cpp ./Game/Game.cpp ./Renderer/GL20Renderer.cpp \
 ./EntitySystem/EntitySystem.cpp TheGame.cpp 
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -landroid -lGLESv2 -lEGL
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := lua ##this line causes crash
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_CFLAGS+=$(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Do you have any idea how can I deal with this :/ ?
I looked into similar questions, but them don't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had very similar problem. Finally ended up compiling libraries in separate mk files.

I think this answer might help you. [Android NDK linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769)