# Where to place .so file so that it gets included in the final build

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I've a .so file which is being referenced by other project in AOSP system package.
To make referencing possible I've created a new project in AOSP/external package with two files in it viz Android.mk and the xyz.so file. The Android.mk looks like following.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := customutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := xyz.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

During the compilation it gives me following error.

make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/crespo/obj/lib/customutil.so', needed by`out/target/product/crespo/obj/EXECUTABLES/abc_agent_intermediates/LINKED/abc_agent'.  Stop.

Where should I keep, xyz.so file or what changes should I make so that when I build AOSP, it won't trow this error?

---

Sushil

Comment: If you are looking to build a separate lib.so file and you use it within your main lib.so then this answer might help with step to follow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Comment: The error message looks suspicious. I would expect a message about lib/libcustomutil.so, but if you get lib/customutil.so you probably have a wrong Android.mk for abc_agent.

Answer (score 1):

Your module rules are a problem.

when you have a pre-built library with `LOCAL_MODULE := customutil`, then the linker will get the additional flag `-lcustomutil`. Thus your `LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=` needs to be `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcustomutil.so`

Thus the Android.mk section should be:

```
# Prebuilt Lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := xyx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libxyz.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This also means that you need to rename the library appropriately or set the module name according to the library name.

Answer (score 0):

By default, for prebuilts, LOCAL_SRC_FILES are relative to your current LOCAL_PATH definition, so if your Android.mk is under `$PROJECT/jni/Android.mk`, you should put it at `$PROJECT/jni/xyz.so`

The name should also be probable libxyz.so instead of xyz.so (though that might work without the lib prefix).

If you plan to support several CPU ABIs, try to use a sub-directory, as in:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libxyz
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libxyz.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And place the files under:

```
$PROJECT/jni/armeabi/libxyz.so
$PROJECT/jni/armeabi-v7a/libxyz.so
$PROJECT/jni/x86/libxyz.so
...
```

Finally, you can also use an absolute path for LOCAL_SRC_FILES, and the build system will pick the file from there.

Answer (score 0):

I added my prebuilt .so file in external folder of AOSP source code as following:-

Step 1 :- I have created one folder(let say myLibs) inside external folder of AOSP
 then I added my .so file in it and added following code in Android.mk file

```
# Prebuilt Lib
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libMyabc  # your lib name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libMyabc.so
  # your lib .so file name
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then  i added my shared libs name in Frameworks/base/core/jni/Android.mk file in LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES section.

Now it is generation my .so file in out/target/product/generic/obj/lib folder

Thanks
Happy Coding...