# how to setup a prebuilt library in jni for android?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, java-native-interface

> hi, i need to use a prebuilt library in my native code so i am placing the library following the example in ndk/samples/native-activity. Below is the structure. Please some one help me out with this error, dsplink.h can not be found. Thanks in advance :)

[image: directory structure]

[image: Android.mk]

[image: the error]

[image: hello-jni.c]

Comment: If you are trying to build a separate lib.so file and you use it within your main lib.so the you this answer might help with step to follow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Answer (score 1):

I thin Vladimir was on the right track. 
But don't keep the static lib in the obj folder since that one is delete every run, instead create a jni/modules/precompiled or something and put the stuff there...

what you have is a precompiled static lib. that's what the .a file is. 
it's meant to add it to a compilation process so that it'll be in the final binary. 
so what you should have is :

```
#
# DSPLINK
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := dsplink
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := [path-to-prebuilt-lib]/libdsplink.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := [path-to-dsplink-headers-folder]
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and also dont forget to include it for the linker in the project .. so below this section in the main shared lib add this line :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := dsplink
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C file includes **dsplink.h** file. If you have it, you should add the full path to this file in `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`, e.g.

```
LOCAL_MODULE     := jnihello
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inlcudes
```

By the way, if **dsplink.a** file is prebuilt, you will be on the safe side to keep it outside of the **libs/** folder, so that **`make clean`** does not delete it. You can use something like

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/prebuilt/dsplink.a
```

to help the linker find the file.

Comment: and what happens when that dsplink.h file is dependent on many other header files??? i have to add them all right?? i dont want to add all the header files like this, it looks messy......

Comment: The nature of C language is that all include files must be available to the compiler. But it is not required to put all dsplink-related files under the project root. Wherever they are located, the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` and `LOCAL_LDLIBS` should let the compiler find them.

Comment: thats the path where all the header files are present. but i still get no dsplink.h error.....

Comment: You should use a path without spaces for `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`, like `C:/Docume~1/xavier~1/...`

Answer (score 0):

libmath-prebuilt.so is a prebuilt library which has some functions which are used by buyya_read.c. First generate libmath-prebuilt.so using ndk-build and keep in jni folder where buyya_read.c is kept in ur project in elcipse.

```
Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := math-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = libmath-prebuilt.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := buyya_read
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := buyya_read.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := math-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You see the project directory structure in below image.
[image: Project Dir Structure]

Answer (score -1):

You should define prebuilt library `dsplink` in your Android.mk before `jnihello` project:

```
#
# DSPLINK
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := dsplink
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := [path]/libs/armeabi/libdsplink.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := [directory-with-dsplink.h-file]
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
...
# jnihello
```