# building libxml2 from source for android as static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, libxml2

I am writing simple C library for Android

I am trying to build libxml2 from the source code as static library, so I can use it in my code. I am using Eclipse and I want to use libxml2 in NDK, in my C functions.

I imported the source code to new folder called libxml into a project, and in Android.mk I put this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libmyxml2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ...  all c files from libxml .. \
    ...
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

In my shared library part:  `LOCAL_MODULE := myxml2`

In project Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes .. I have the directory to the include files under GNU C for libxml

When I start build, compilator tels me error: No such file or directory
It can't find the includes.

I am on windows system.

Is there any tutorial or some advice how can I use libxml2 in my C code in NDK in simple understanding way?

How to build libxml2 by miself for the android and start to using it under Eclipse?

Thank you

Comment: If you are trying to build a separate lib.so file and you use it within your main lib.so the you this answer might help with step to follow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer how to build libxml2 as static library for android. [Using libxml for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052089/using-libxml-for-android)
You could easily link it to app you're writing in case of the static library succesfully built. You could also download libxml2 with Android.mk file already written for you and build it using NDK (https://github.com/android/platform_external_libxml2).

Comment: I seem to have done it right, following the above github and build it, but somehow it fails with the following linker error. 
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libxml2.so
/usr/local/src/android-ndk-r9c/Android_libxml2/jni/encoding.c:109: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_open_52'
/usr/local/src/android-ndk-r9c/Android_libxml2/jni/encoding.c:115: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_setToUCallBack_52'
/usr/local/src/android-ndk-r9c/Android_libxml2/jni/encoding.c:119: error: undefined reference to 'ucnv_setFromUCallBack_52'

And few more.

Comment: I have run the command on the readme with success. Even run the tests stated and they worked. But where is now the compiled library located?