# Using libxml for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libxml2

We have an application working fine for Mac and Windows platform, now targeting for Android and iOS, 
Application using libxml for parsing of XML data, and my question is  ?

1 -- Do i need to build libxml for Android platform or its already there as a part of NDK ?

if need to build any pointers how to start ?

Comment: It's not a part of NDK. For pointers how to start - start with the NDK readme, move on to Java's JNI docs.

Comment: thanks for your comment, actually i am aware of NDK Environment, what i want to know is, Having OSX Platform, how to compile libxml for Android, some cross compilation process to compile libxml for Android platform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

Write an Android.mk that can successfully build libxml, and depend on the result of that in your main Android.mk.  You can try to build libxml natively (using the configure script and make) on your Mac to get an idea of what files need to be built, and if any special flags need to be passed.

Or, Use libxml's configure script and build libxml for Android using the NDK's toolchain.  You'll have to do something like this:

```
NDK_ROOT=/path/to/ndk
API_LEVEL=YOUR_API_LEVEL
SYSROOT=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-$API_LEVEL/arch-arm

export CC="$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/Darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$SYSROOT"
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$SYSROOT"

./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --disable-shared
make libxml2.la
```

Technically the host triplet for Android is `arm-linux-androideabi`, but most configure scripts don't recognize it, and for our purposes here, `-gnueabi` is close enough.

I ended up suggesting `make libxml2.la` rather than just `make` because the tests weren't building properly.  The resulting library will end up in the `.libs/` folder.

The second method might be a little easier, but if you intend to build your app for multiple architectures (arm, armv7-a, maybe even x86 and mips), writing your own Android.mk will save you time in the long run.

Comment: @keinos : Thanks i will try and let you know

Comment: Hey, the tests aren't building because of the missing glob files. Just have a look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/vSH6MWPD0Vk

Comment: It's not clear enough for me... **libxml2 is "the standard" for Android**?  Or there are another "Java world" XML parser... Or, by default, no XML parser at commom Android?