# Android.mk: shared library not linked

Tags: linker, makefile, android-ndk

I am trying to include my library `libtest.so` into another library.

`libtest.so` is successfully compiled and in the folder:

`$PROJECT/obj/local/armeabi/libtest.so`

When I tried to use it in my `Android.mk` file, I couldn't use its functionality. I didn't get an error message however, not even if I included a library that doesn't exist.

This is my `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := test
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := test

LOCAL_MODULE     := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := myLib.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I built this, I just got a lot of `"No such file or directory"` errors from my includes from the library:

```
jni/myLib.cpp:10:24: error: myinclude.h: No such file or directory
```

`myinclude.h` is a file from the library. Every forum answer seems to say that `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := test` or `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest` would be enough to use the library.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Answer (score 0):

add the directory which contain myinclude.h to LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /dir/to/your/include/files/
```

Comment: it is in the same directory so that cant be it :( i'm expecting a problem finding the libtest.so file. pointing LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to the libtest.so file didnt work either

Comment: can you list ur detailed project directory structure? or can you share your project for debugging if  possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the library's responsibility to tell you what to include, despite that it may solve the problem temporarily, using `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` to specify include files written by somebody else (as suggested in [the answer by Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11575971/142239)) is not a good idea in terms of maintainability.

One of the problems is that your problem is that the `Android.mk` file of `libtest` is not correctly written. If it exports any header files, you should add `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /path/to/include-dir` to it.

Here is an example (taken from `$NDK_ROOT/samples/module-exports/jni/Android.mk`):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DFOO=2
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := bar
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bar/bar.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := zoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := zoo/zoo.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bar
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here, the first library is `foo`. It is built as a static library (see `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`). It exports the header directory with:

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
```

The second library is `bar`, it is a shared library (see `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar`). When it references `foo` with:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
```

the headers in `foo` will be search as if `-I$LOCAL_PATH/foo` has been specified to `gcc`.
Note that it also export its own header directory with:

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar
```

The third library is `zoo`, it is a shared library. It references the `bar` library. This demonstrates that a shared library can include another shared library without any problem.

Please include more of your configurations if this doesn't solve your problem.